# Java10: Hibernate 5.3: The package org.hibernate.annotations is not accessible

Tags: java, hibernate, java-10

I'm using hibernate 5.3 with Java 10 in eclipse(photon). While using hibernate annotation getting compilation error eg:

> The package `org.hibernate.annotations` is not accessible

I have created module-info class and added module

> org.hibernate.orm.core
>
> org.hibernate.common.annotation

Comment: You need to add further more details as how are you trying to access it and is your project modular or just trying to access the dependency on classpath?

Comment: @ArunKumar I agree with nullpointer, you need to add more information: Are you using a build tool? Which one and which version? Did you add the dependency? Which artifact? Did you create a `module-info.java`?